# The sorting function is not sorting user input's lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
Numbers = []
QN = input("what are the numbers")
Numbers.append(QN)

def Median():
  median = sorted(Numbers)
  print ("Sorted:", median)
Median()
```

This my code and I am trying to make a program where the user enters a list of numbers than the program lists them from least to greatest using the sort function. The problem is that it is not printing the sorted list and it is printing the original unsorted list. I can't figure out the problem, The list of numbers the user gave, is added to the list but it appears that the list is not being sorted.

Comment: `QN = input("what are the numbers")` defined `QN` to be a single string. You presumably want to split that string and convert it to ints or floats. Your code does not even attempt that. Also, the median of a list is not the sorted list, and functions should typically `return` values rather than `print` them.

Comment: Another problem is that a well-written function should depend only on the arguments passed to it, and not on global variables. A function with no arguments that operates exclusively on global variables and then is instantly invoked once is quite pointless. A final point, is that upper case names are not idiomatic names for functions in Python. Use lower case, reserving upper case for class definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The sorted function takes a list and sorts it's elements.
So,

```
In [2]: sorted([1])                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[2]: [1]
```

A list of one element is already considered sorted because there is no ordering for one number.

```
In [1]: sorted([312,321,213])                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[1]: [213, 312, 321]
```

The three are considered as numbers and are sorted accordingly.

```
In [2]: sorted(['312','33','321'])                                                                                                                                                             
Out[2]: ['312', '321', '33']
```

There are considered strings and are sorted **alphabetically**

```
In [3]: sorted('231')                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[3]: ['1', '2', '3']
```

A string is also considered a list of characters so the characters are sorted alphabetically.

```
QN = input("what are the numbers")

def Median():
  median = sorted(QN)
  print ("Sorted:", median)
Median()
```

This is how you can make your current code work.

But this is probably what you want to do:

```
def Median(lst): 
  median = sorted(lst) 
  return median # you have to work on this further to actually calculate the median, this will just return the sorted list.


Numbers = [] 
QN = 'placeholder' # put a placeholder so we can enter the loop 
print('enter your numbers, one number in each line, empty line to end') 
while (QN != ''): 
  QN = input() 
  if (QN != ''): 
    Numbers.append(int(QN)) # make sure you put the int() because you don't want to consider the numbers as strings because in that case they will be sorted alphabetically. 


print ("Sorted:", Median(Numbers))
```

result:

```
enter your numbers, one number in each line, empty line to end
1
32
23
21
24

Sorted: [1, 21, 23, 24, 32]
```

Comment: @JohnColeman what makes you think you can give a comma separated list of numbers?

Comment: @PalakKumarJha as for the problem with strings, please see my lower code, in which I have used `int()` conversion.

Comment: @PalakKumarJha if you note the OP's question they have said: *"The problem is that it is not printing the sorted list and it is printing the original unsorted list."* So, what I have done was to first address their current problem and finally give them my advice on how to achieve what they would probably want to achieve.

Comment: @HareshSenthilkumar 1. you were working an array of one item, ['1241']. 2. you were only getting one number from the user(calling input() once) and 3. you were not converting the string input of user to integers for having a natural sort. when you sort an array of string they will be sorted alphabetically but you want natural sort so you should convert the strings that you get from the `input` function to integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
Numbers = []
A = int(input("how many numbers are in the list"))
time.sleep(.5)
print ("Can you please enter the numbers?")
time.sleep(.3)
for i in range(A):
  data = int(input())
  Numbers.append(data)

def Median():
  median = sorted(Numbers)
  print median
  if A%2 == 0:
    one = int(A/2) - 1  
    two = one + 1
    One = median[one]
    Two = median[two]
    sum = (One + Two)
    Ans = sum/2
    print ("The median is " + str(Ans))
  else:
    one = int(A/2)  
    One = median[one]
    print ("The median is " + str(One))
```

This seems to work. will this code work?